# how to split long regex patterns defined in dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

During the pycodestyle check observed as line is too long, 
How we need to split this, please help

```
 self.pattern_dict = {"cli_snmpv3config_pattern5": r"Trap\s+Entry\s+(\d+):\s+(.+)\s+Trap\s+Port:\s+(\d+)\s+Trap\s+User:\s+(.+)\s+Trap\s+recipient\s+Severity\s+level:\s+(\d+)\s+Notify\s+Type:\s(.+)",}

snmpv3_pattern5 = self.pattern_dict['cli_snmpv3config_pattern5']
s5 = re.findall(snmpv3_pattern5, output, flags=re.I | re.M)
```

Comment: Files that have failed the pycodestyle check
--------------------------------------------
 E501 line too long (157 > 120 characters)

Answer (score 0):

The error code for this is E501. It shows itself if the line is more than 82 chars. In your case this might be 120.

`E501 line too long (82 characters)`
The easy work around is to put a comment at the end of your long line: `# nopep8`

`Lines with a # nopep8 at the end will not issue errors on line length E501`